# Android TabHost, jump between Activities

Tags: android, android-tabhost, stack-overflow

There is a problem with my TabHost.

I want to jump from an Overview-Activity in a new "detailed" activity without loosing my "TabBar".

I use this function for this:

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {       
    try
    {           
        Activity ac = (Activity) context;   
        ActivityGroup ag = (ActivityGroup) ac.getParent();      
        View view = ag.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();                           
        ((Activity) context).setContentView(view);          

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("ERRR",e.toString());
    }

}
```

This works fine...

But i want to jump in the "detailed" activity and when i'am in there, i want to jump back (with a Button, not the Back Button) into the overview activity with special parameters.. after 2 jumps i get an stackoverflow error , but why ?

Overview Acitcity:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(context,Detailed.class);  
replaceContentView("Detaield",i1);
```

In the "Detailed Activity" i use this to jump back:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(context,Overview.class);  
i1.putExtra("extradata","try");
replaceContentView("Overview",i1);
```